# Golang unsigned URL

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I have the next code to get URL from Amazon, but I need that URL looks something like

https://vis3dev.s3.amazonaws.com/359952_1550525274.mp4

and not

[https://vis3dev.s3.amazonaws.com/266295041.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIE4CD00A5BW7WNTQ%2F20190220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190220T193732Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ba800af2fb7b314df2f47a589165558ae50264164c686314b6d73eab2975d8f1](https://vis3dev.s3.amazonaws.com/266295041.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIE4CD73A5BW7WNTQ%2F20190220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190220T193732Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ba839af2fb7b314df2f47a589165558ae50264164c686314b6d73eab2975d8f1)

```
func GetFileLink(svc *session.Session) error {
    req, _ := s3.New(svc).GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(AwsBucket),
        Key:    aws.String(NameFile + ".mp4"),
    })

    url, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(url)

    return err
}
```

Comment: The url utils contain all you are looking for: Identification of parameters and base url. Alternative you can use a string split on "?".

Comment: I tried use [https://vis3dev.s3.amazonaws.com/266295041.mp4](https://vis3dev.s3.amazonaws.com/266295041.mp4) but doesn't work always I have `the file doesn't have correct format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`acl := "public-read"`

I fixed it changing the upload file adding `ACL:           aws.String(acl),`